# Initialize autocomplete on view form for Rails 3.2?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, autocomplete

Here is a line of code in view form to attached the autocomplete data source to the field `item_name_autocomplte`:

```
<%= f.input :item_name_autocomplete, :label => t("Item Name"), :input_html => { data: {autocomplete_source: SUBURI + base_materialx.autocomplete_parts_path}} %>
```

And the autocomplete is initialized in .js file under assets:

```
$(function() {
    return $('#item_name_autocomplete').autocomplete({
            minLength: 1,
            source: $('#item_name_autocomplete').data('autocomplete-source'),
            select: function(event, ui) {
                $(this).val(ui.item.value);
            }
      });
});
```

Is there a way the above initialization code can be integrated into the view form? So when the view form is rendered, the autocomplete is initialized at the same time. The autocomplete field is dynamically inserted onto the view by user and the id of the element would be unique for each insertion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not put js code straight into you view. Instead, use `content_for :smth` and `yield :smth` within your `<head>` tag, e.g:

```
# application layout:
<body>
  ...
  ...
  <%= yield :additional_javascripts %>
</body>

# users/_form.html.erb:
<% content_for :additional_javascripts do %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "some_script" %>
<% end %>
```

With such approach, your view is clean and js separated. Finally, `some_script.js` content:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#item_name_autocomplete').autocomplete({
            minLength: 1,
            source: $('#item_name_autocomplete').data('autocomplete-source'),
            select: function(event, ui) {
                $(this).val(ui.item.value);
            }
      });
});
```

Comment: @@blelump, very interesting idea. adding a :additional_javascripts to the application.html.erb and use it in partial view to hook up with a snippet of js code which is specifically for the view.

Comment: There is another reason we want to initialize it along with the insertion. The id of the element is dynamic and unique for every insertion.

Comment: Here comes `data` attribute. You can add any data to any DOM element in a such manner: `<div data-id='1234'></div>`. Then, with jQuery simply `$("div").data("id")`. That's how you should solve it here.